# Django websocket website returning an empty JSON/dictionary when I try to reference the user's username

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am building a django website where users can chat with each other and I am using channels for its development.
I intended on programming it in such a way that the user's profile pic would be beside their message with their username on top of their message. But right now, I am not seeing
their profile photo nor their username. I am just getting the alt text instead of their profile photo, and a '{}' beside their username. I have added console.log() and print()
statements in various places inside of my code for debugging it which I will show in the output.
The following is routing.py:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatRoomConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

The following is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import Profile

def home(request):
    context = {
        
    }
    return render(request, 'common_anime_chat/index.html', context)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'common_anime_chat/about.html')

def room(request, room_name):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'common_anime_chat/chatroom.html', {
            'room_name':room_name
        })
    else:
        messages.success(request, f'You need to log in to start conversations.')
        return redirect('login')

def get_user_profile_pictures(request):
    # Get all users
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()

    # Create a dictionary to store the profile picture URLs for each user
    profile_pictures = {}
    for profile in profiles:
        # Check if the user has a profile picture
        print(profile.user_id)
        profile_pictures[profile.user_id] = profile.profile_picture.url
    print(profile_pictures)

    return JsonResponse(profile_pictures)
```

The following is consumers.py (the file that handles the logic behind the websocket):

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    async def receive(self, text_data):
         text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
         message = text_data_json['message']
         username = text_data_json['username']

         await self.channel_layer.group_send(
              self.room_group_name,
              {
                   'type':'chatroom_message',
                   'message':message,
                   'username':username,
              }
         )

    async def chatroom_message(self, event):
         message = event['message']
         username = str(event['username'])

         await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
              'message':message,
              'username':username,
         }))
```

The following is chatroom.html:

```
{% extends 'common_anime_chat/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block stylesheet %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'chatroom.css' %}">
{% endblock stylesheet %}
{% block content %}
<div class="chat-container">
  <div id="chat-messages"></div>
  <input type="text" id="input" size="80">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send">
</div>

{{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
{{ request.user.username|json_script:"user_username" }}
<script>
    const hardcodedProfilePictures = {
        'itsmyname': '/media/profile_pictures/profile1.png',
        'user123': '/media/profile_picturues/profile2.png',
        // Add more hardcoded profile pictures here for other usernames
    };

    document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function (e) {
        const messageInputDOM = document.querySelector('#input');
        const message = messageInputDOM.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message,
            'username': user_username,
        }));
        messageInputDOM.value = '';
    };

    const chatMessagesDOM = document.querySelector('#chat-messages');
    const userUsername = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_username').textContent);
    console.log(userUsername)
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

    // Object to store profile pictures associated with usernames
    let profilePictures = {};

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' +
        window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' +
        roomName +
        '/'
    );
    chatSocket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened.');
};

chatSocket.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
};

chatSocket.onerror = function (error) {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
};

    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data.message);
        const username = data.username.toString()
        console.log("data.username: "+username)

        const messageContainer = document.createElement('div');
        messageContainer.classList.add('chat-message');

        const profilePicture = document.createElement('img');
        // profilePicture.src = profilePictures[data.username] || '/media/profile_pics/default.png';
        profilePicture.src = hardcodedProfilePictures[username]
        profilePicture.alt = 'Profile Picture';
        profilePicture.classList.add('profile-picture');
        messageContainer.appendChild(profilePicture);

        const messageContent = document.createElement('span');
        messageContent.classList.add('message-content');

        const usernameSpan = document.createElement('span');
        usernameSpan.classList.add('username');
        usernameSpan.textContent = username; // Use the username from the message data
        messageContent.appendChild(usernameSpan);

        const messageSpan = document.createElement('span');
        messageSpan.textContent = data.message;
        messageContent.appendChild(messageSpan);

        messageContainer.appendChild(messageContent);

        chatMessagesDOM.appendChild(messageContainer);
    };

    // Fetch and load profile pictures for each user
    fetch('/api/get_user_profile_pictures/') // Change this URL to the endpoint that provides profile picture URLs for all users
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            profilePictures = data;
            console.log(profilePictures)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(profilePictures)
            console.error('Error loading profile pictures:', error);
        });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

The following is the output of the python in the terminal:

```
2
3
6
{2: '/media/profile_pics/Mikasas_face_3t29ppY.jpg', 3: '/media/profile_pics/4.jpg', 6: '/media/profile_pics/default.png'}
```

The following is the output in the console (the output of the JS code):

```
itsmyname
(index):126 Object
(index):77 WebSocket connection opened.
(index):90 hi
(index):92 data.username: {}
undefined:1     GET http://localhost:8000/chat/django/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

To be specific:
I'm talking about the chatSocket.onmessage function where I'm getting the data received from the code in consumers.py which is returning an empty dictionary/JSON object when trying to refer to its "username" key. That particular piece of code should return the user's username who sent that particular message. I don't really know whether it's the JS code causing this or the code in consumers.py file.

Btw, data.username = username in the JS code.

Edit:
I have narrowed down that the following JS and consumers.py code are causing my problems.
JS code:

```
    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log('Username fetched from the django jinja template: '+ JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_username').textContent))
        console.log(e)
        console.log(data.message);
        const username = data.username.toString()
        console.log("data.username: "+username)
        console.log(data.tester_message)
```

consumers.py code:

```
    async def chatroom_message(self, event):
         message = event['message']
         username= str(event['username'])

         await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
              'message':message,
              'username':'User in chatroom message',
              'tester_message':'tester message in chatroom message'
         }))
```

The following is the  output from the console when I send a simple "hi" message

```
(index):129 Object
(index):77 WebSocket connection opened.
(index):90 Username fetched from the django jinja template: itsmyname
(index):91 MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: '{"message": "hi", "username": "User in chatroom me…r_message": "tester message in chatroom message"}', origin: 'ws://localhost:8000', lastEventId: '', source: null, …}isTrusted: truebubbles: falsecancelBubble: falsecancelable: falsecomposed: falsecurrentTarget: WebSocket {url: 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/chat/django/', readyState: 1, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}data: "{\"message\": \"hi\", \"username\": \"User in chatroom message\", \"tester_message\": \"tester message in chatroom message\"}"defaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0lastEventId: ""origin: "ws://localhost:8000"ports: []returnValue: truesource: nullsrcElement: WebSocket {url: 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/chat/django/', readyState: 1, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}target: WebSocket {url: 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/chat/django/', readyState: 1, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}timeStamp: 15573.399999976158type: "message"userActivation: null[[Prototype]]: MessageEvent
(index):92 hi
(index):94 data.username: User in chatroom message
(index):95 tester message in chatroom message
undefined:1     GET http://localhost:8000/chat/django/undefined 404 (Not Found)
Image (async)
chatSocket.onmessage @ (index):102
```

I have changed the content of the chatroom_message function as that was being called. I am styll learning about this topic so I need to figure out why that is being called though...
But that aside, that function is being called (not receiver, even in the other person's chat and their POV) whenever a message is being sent so I added some dummy data to it so that I could debug it
The problem in this instance is that I am not able to get the user's username when they are logged in to my site using websockets.

Edit 2: I added a print statement after the variable declaration inside the chatroom_message function:

```
    async def chatroom_message(self, event):
         message = event['message']
         username= event['username']
         print("Username:",username)

         await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
              'message':message,
              'username':'User in chatroom message',
              'tester_message':'tester message in chatroom message'
         }))
```

This was the output when I printed that out:

```
Username: Username in receive function
```

This is the dummy data inside the receive function.
After switching the values from dummy data to the actual user data as follows:

```
    async def receive(self, text_data):
         text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
         message = text_data_json['message']
         self.username = text_data_json['username']

         await self.channel_layer.group_send(
              self.room_group_name,
              {
                   'type':'chatroom_message',
                   'message':message,
                   'username':self.username,
                   'tester_message':'tester message in receive function'
              }
         )
```

I got the following output:

```
Username: {}
```

So my understanding tells me if I am able to access the user's details (their username in this case) inside the receive() function, my problem will be solved.

Comment: Have you tried just try putting this {{request.user.username}} in your dictionary instead?  "username":"{{request.user.username}}"

Comment: @AdamJames I don't know which dictionary you are talking about but I have put some useful information in the post after editing it so please check it out!

Comment: In this function in your chatroom.htm. document.querySelector('#submit').onclick.       I think this line is your problem.  It doesn't seem to be setting the username.  request.user.username|json_script:"user_username"